# JS/CSS duplicate load and 404 Error

Tags: performance

We have a strange issue on one of our WordPress sites. Performance has been bad recently and we discovered that many JS and CSS files are a) loaded twice and b) the duplicate load results in a 404 error. Follow is a screenshot from Developer Tools:

[image: Developer Tools Screenshot]

As you can see in this filtered view, bootstrap js and css are loadeded twice. Once, from the theme folder, they load fine. Then a second time with a different (root) path - which obviously does not exist - it results in a 404 error. This happens to ~80% of all CSS and JS files.

Following is the environment we are using:

- WordPress 4.3.1
- Oxygen theme

Plugins

- AddFunc Head & Footer Code
- Admin Columns - ACF add-on
- Admin Columns Pro
- Advanced Custom Fields Pro
- Akismet
- Better Search Replace Pro
- Captcha by BestWebSoft
- Category Redirect
- Custom Field Bulk Editor
- Custom Login
- Custom Permalinks
- Custom Post Type UI
- Duplicate Post
- DZS Layouter
- Easy Social Share Buttons for WordPress
- Easy Updates Manager
- External Links
- Feefo Plugin for Backyard Travel
- Fresh Custom Code
- Fresh Custom Loops
- Fresh File Editor
- Fresh Framework
- Fresh Sidebar Manager
- Hide Admin Bar
- iframe
- Layered Popups
- LionScripts: IP Blocker Lite
- MailChimp for WordPress Pro
- Ninja Forms
- Ninja Forms - Conditional Logic
- Ninja Forms - Layout & Styles
- Ninja Forms - MailChimp
- Ninja Forms - PopControl
- Ninja Forms - Trello
- Ninja Forms - User Analytics
- Ninja Forms - Webhooks
- No Update Nag
- NS Custom Fields Analysis for WordPress SEO
- One-Click Child Theme
- P3 (Plugin Performance Profiler)
- Password Protected
- Popup Maker
- Popup Maker - Advanced Theme Builder
- Popup Maker - Exit Intent Popups
- Regenerate Thumbnails
- Revolution Slider
- Schema App Structured Data
- Searchford WordPress Advanced Search
- Shortcodes for Oxygen Theme
- Stag Custom Sidebars
- Sucuri Security - Auditing, Malware Scanner and Hardening
- UberMenu 3 - The Ultimate WordPress Mega Menu
- VaultPress
- White Label Branding for WordPress
- WordPress Importer
- Wordpress Post Grid/List Layout With Carousel
- Wordpress Post Grid/List Layout With Carousel (EXTENSION)
- WP All Import - ACF Add-On
- WP All Import Pro
- Yoast SEO
- Zopim Widget

We are also using *CloudFlare* for caching. Recently we changed the cache duration from 8 days to 8 hours on CF.

Does anybody have any idea what could cause this issue?

Thank you in advance for any hints.

EXODev

Comment: Network errors and a list of plugins isn't useful information.

Comment: What information would be then? We want to figure out what causes this issue and I just wanted to give as much information as possible.

Comment: Useful information would include the specific code where the links are being generated.  Also details about what you have tried so far and your results. If your expecting someone will troubleshoot this for you you should read the [Tour](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: That's a lot of plugins! You probably need to figure out which plugin is loading the incorrect URLs. No-one here is going to know all those plugins intimately; it sounds like you might need to hire a developer to optimise the site for you.

Comment: BillK: I am not expecting anybody to troubleshoot this. I am wondering if somebody has experienced something similar before and what the cause was. This will be a hint where to start digging.
Tim: Yeah, I know. Unfortunately, I inherited the site in this state. Development through plugins. ;)

Comment: Check the theme script and style queue and registration functions. I had a plugin that would load a .css twice and it was due to exactly that. As for the 404, well that same function, if duplicated in the theme somewhere, might have a different file path.

Comment: All the info you have given is useless without definitive debugging info. You should start by clearing caches, set debugging to true and check for obvious bugs, then start by deactivating plugins until the error goes away, and finally test with a bundled theme

Comment: @EXODev , using WP 4.3.1 ?

Comment: Thanks, Jamerson. I will look into this.
Pieter Goosen: Yeah, caches have been cleared and disabled, including CloudFlare. Doesn't resolve the issue at this point.
bravokeyl: I know. Like I said, this was dumped on me. As you can see in the plugin list: updating will not be a one-click-two-clicks process. This will need a proper upgrade methodology. I am not lead on this project and am just trying to support. It's just an issue that I have never seen in 15 years of web dev. (Then again, I seldom use WordPress for projects.)

Comment: No worries @EXODev - I would be happy to install the theme in our sandbox and test it to determine if it is indeed the theme.

Comment: It's definitely not the theme. This issue does not occur on the development server. We have also established, that it's not the CF cache, as stopping it does not resolve the issue. Going through the plugins list now.

Comment: OK. I have investigated the issue further and it seems the 'double posting' is coming, duh, from the parent theme. The question then becomes: why is the child theme (themes/mytheme-child/) loading assets correctly while the parent theme (themes/mytheme/) is redirecting to the root and throwing a 404 error? So far, no plugin seems to be the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. The issue can be regarded as closed. The issue was:

A dev had made changes to .htaccess which resulted in the parent theme assets to be redirected to the uri root - resulting in 404 errors for all those assets.

Thanks for all input.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to hear this.

That is a lot of plugins!

Since you have no worries installing/using so many, I have to ask: have to tried using a plugin to minimize and impact performance of Javascript and CSS?

Might be worth trying something like this just to see how it impacts overall performance: https://wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/

Also, have to you looked into memory usage on the server?

Might be worthwhile to know with certainty what is slowing things down so much. I would recommend that you start there.

Comment: Thanks wax. But they have tried that before and it actually broke the site altogether.